# plot multiple dataframes using loop in python

Tags: python

please I am a beginner in Python, I would like to use the "for" loop to load and plot multiple dataframes from different folders on the same plot , I started to write a script, but I got stuck , please if you can help me with this.
i manage to create the plots for all "sim_000",.., sim_005",
but I would like to automate it by creating a loop, could you please help me how to do that

```
   import pandas as pd
   import os
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   f= ("40","50","60")
   storage = {}
   for i in f:
     for j in range(6):
        storage[(i,j)] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join("/Simulation_Results/10km/","res_"f"{i}",f"sim_{str(j).zfill(3)}","velocity.csv"),sep='\\s+',header=None)
```

######### plot ##########################

```
   fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots()

   ax0.plot(storage[("40",0)].loc[:,1],storage[("40",0)].loc[:,0],'-', label = "res_40 ")
   ax0.plot(storage[("50",0)].loc[:,1],storage[("50",0)].loc[:,0],'-', label = "res_50 ")
   ax0.plot(storage[("60",0)].loc[:,1],storage[("60",0)].loc[:,0],'-', label = "res_60 ")
   ax0.set_xlabel("X-label for axis")
   ax0.set_ylabel("y-label for axis")
   ax0.legend(loc="upper left")
   ax0.set_title(" sim_000")
fig0.savefig("sim_000.png",format='png',dpi=150)
   #########################
   fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
   ax1.plot(storage[("40",1)].loc[:,1],storage[("40",1)].loc[:,0],'-',                                           label = "res_40 ")
   ax1.plot(storage[("50",1)].loc[:,1],storage[("50",1)].loc[:,0],'-', label = "res_50 ")
   ax1.plot(storage[("60",1)].loc[:,1],storage[("60",1)].loc[:,0],'-', label = "res_60 ")
   ax1.set_xlabel("X-label for axis")
   ax1.set_ylabel("y-label for axis")
   ax1.legend(loc="upper left")
   ax1.set_title(" sim_001")
fig1.savefig("sim_001.png",format='png',dpi=150)

 ##########################
   
 fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
   ax2.plot(storage[("40",1)].loc[:,1],storage[("40",1)].loc[:,0],'-', label = "res_40 ")
   ax2.plot(storage[("50",1)].loc[:,1],storage[("50",1)].loc[:,0],'-', label = "res_50 ")
   ax2.plot(storage[("60",1)].loc[:,1],storage[("60",1)].loc[:,0],'-', label = "res_60 ")
   ax2.set_xlabel("X-label for axis")
   ax2.set_ylabel("y-label for axis")
   ax2.legend(loc="upper left")
   ax2.set_title(" sim_002")
   fig2.savefig("sim_002.png",format='png',dpi=150)
   plt.show()
```

#############################

Comment: For this task, Matplotlib is not the best option, in my opinion. Matplotlib is awesome for numerical plots, but you are trying to plot a graph, with edges and nodes. I suggest you take a look at PyGraphviz: https://pygraphviz.github.io/

Comment: actually, I'm trying to plot numerical plots  not a graph ,